# Rails: What is the proper way to render a partial in a js.erb file 3.2.7

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've read posts saying that it is not possible to render a partial in a js.erb file.  What is the proper way to accomplish this?

I am trying to use jquery ui to render a contact form in a dialog box.

```
var contactHtml = $('<div></div>').html("test").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'hi'
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
       $('<div></div>').html("<%= j(render :partial => 'example/file') %>")
```

just remember to escape your render call with j (synonymous with escape_javascript). You will use this approach a lot when you are dealing with ajax calls.

Edit

If you are attempting this from your assets folder, this is not possible and you will get the undefined method render error. Here is a [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370399/rails-js-erb-file-cannot-find-method-render) for more details

Comment: This produces the following error which is why I posted this question: [19:02:51.277] Error: NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007ff2b4ad1d40>:0x007ff2b7648708>

Comment: Where is this js.erb file located?

Comment: So add this to my views folder?  Is this still compiled?

Comment: Yes you can try that, you should not get a render error. I have never used the dialog plugin so I am not sure how it will function.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but I don't see the need to start reorganizing my files.  I just used ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I still used a partial for my form, but I rendered it with ajax.

In my js.erb file

```
  var contactHtml = $('<div></div>').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Get a Free Estimate',
    minWidth:400,
    close: function(){$(this).empty();}
});
$('#consultation').click(function(){
    $.get('/contact_form', function(data){
        contactHtml.append(data);
    });
    contactHtml.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Routes:

```
  match "contact_form" => "application#contact_form", :via => :get
```

Application Controller:

```
  def contact_form
  @contact = Refinery::Contacts::Contact.new
  render :partial => "/contact_form", :locals => {:contact => @contact}
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can do something like below in your js.erb:

```
$("yourclass").javascript_action("<%= escape_javascript(render('partial_name', :local_var_name => @local_var_name)) %>");
```

and in your partial pass locals:

```
  <%= render 'partial_name', :local_var_name => local_var_name %>
```

Hope this helps!