# rails ransack remote true with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, pagination

I've a controller for `WeekDay`. Then I tried to add RanSack in my project. It works good except when I tried to enable `remote true`, it shows only search form. AJAX call is being made, but nothing shows up.

**Controller code**

```
def index
  @q = WeekDay.ransack(params[:q])
  @week_days = @q.result().page(params[:page]).per(10)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @week_days }
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="week_days"><%= render 'week_days' %></div>
```

**_week_days.html.erb**

```
<%= search_form_for @q,remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.label :datum_gteq %>
<%= f.date_field :datum_gteq%>
<%= f.label :datum_lteq %>
<%= f.date_field :datum_lteq %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<table> 
<thead>
<tr>
  <th><%=sort_link @q, :datum %></th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @week_days.each do |week_day| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= l week_day.datum %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', week_day %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_week_day_path(week_day) %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<%= paginate @week_days %>
<br>

<%= link_to 'New Week Day', new_week_day_path %>
```

Comment: Improved grammar and code formatting. Removed 404 errored gist link.

Answer (score 1):

some idea from me is you split the _week_days into partial and then render part of data using ajax, I added new div with name display-area as target for ajax to render and you should create javascripts to render it without reload the page with escape javascripts (j)

_week_days.html.erb

```
<%= render "search" %> 
<%= render "my_data" %>
```

_search.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @q,remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :datum_gteq %>
    <%= f.date_field :datum_gteq%>
    <%= f.label :datum_lteq %>
    <%= f.date_field :datum_lteq %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

_my_data.html.erb

```
<div class="display-area">
    <table> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th><%=sort_link @q, :datum %></th>
                  <th colspan="3"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @week_days.each do |week_day| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= l week_day.datum %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', week_day %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_week_day_path(week_day) %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <%= paginate @week_days %>
    <br>
    <%= link_to 'New Week Day', new_week_day_path %>    
</div>
```

write _weekdays.js.erb inside app/assets/javascripts

```
$('.display-area').html("<%= j render(partial: 'my_data') %>")
```

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007f0a32283a50>:0x007f0a31e26e30>) for that javascript line

Comment: Moved my js.erb into the views folder please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370399/rails-js-erb-file-cannot-find-method-render

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007f28a2780330>:0x007f28a2341c10>):
   i am move it in same folder with html templates rails 5.1

Comment: well actually anything i choose in ransack  is  sent to back on server but it dont  renders at all

Comment: i see in console  as it is send with ajax but it wont render  in  application

Comment: any idea why it wont render   ?